# SQL Query (SQL Server 2008) to retrieve data from two tables and group results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (assume 2 columns: `ID` and `category`). I would like to retrieve records from first table, from second table, group results by category (there are the same categories in two tables) and count them separately. For example:

#### First table:

```
ID | category
-------------
1 | category1
2 | category2
3 | category3
4 | category1
5 | category2
```

#### Second table:

```
ID | category
--------------
a | category1
b | category2
c | category3
d | category3
```

I would like to get results like:

```
category | count(id from 1 table) | count(id from 2 table)
------------------------------------------------------------
category1 |        2 |        1
category2 |        2 |        2
category3 |        1 |        3
```

I try this:

```
SELECT r.AFFECTED_ITEM as usluga,
       COUNT(r.ID) AS problemy,
       (SELECT COUNT(k.ID)
          FROM KNOWNERRORM1 k
         WHERE k.AFFECTED_ITEM = r.AFFECTED_ITEM
      GROUP BY k.AFFECTED_ITEM) AS znane_bledy<br>
FROM ROOTCAUSEM1 r
group by r.AFFECTED_ITEM
```

...but in results there are less records that it should be (because of inner join).

When I used full join there are more records that it should be..

Answer (score 3):

**Made the modifications as per Siva's suggestions.**

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1Grouped.Category, table2Grouped.Category) AS Category, COALESCE(table1Grouped.IDCount, 0) AS Table1IDCount, COALESCE(table2Grouped.IDCount, 0) AS Table2IDCount
FROM
(
    SELECT table1.category, COUNT(table1.ID) AS IDCount
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY table1.category
) AS table1Grouped
    FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT table2.category, COUNT(table2.ID) AS IDCount
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY table2.category
) AS table2Grouped
    ON
table1Grouped.category = table2Grouped.Category
```

Comment: Mark as answered if it helped you.

Comment: @Siva - Thanks for the suggestions, I have made the modifications.

Comment: @Siva - Corrected. It's late at night here. I am not thinking straight. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(Id) AS TableOneCount, 0 AS TableTwoCount
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Category, 0 AS TableOneCount, COUNT(Id) AS TableTwoCount
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Category
```

Sorry if this doesn't work, I'm at home and don't have SQL Server or anything else installed to test it (I'm one of those programmers who doesn't code at home :-p)

Comment: Hi, there is very cute and it almost works (I have conversion error, but it can be fixed). Thank You very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  category,
  table1count = COUNT(CASE tableid WHEN 1 THEN 1 END),
  table2count = COUNT(CASE tableid WHEN 2 THEN 1 END)
FROM (
  SELECT 1, category
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, category
  FROM Table2
) x (tableid, category)
GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Category,(Select count(id) from t1 where t1.Category=t3.Category),(Select count(id) from t2 where t2.Category=t3.Category)
FROM t3

t3 contains

category1
category2
category3